# OpenLayers 3 unit test tips

Tags: openlayers, node-js

I am trying to write some mocha/expect unit tests for my OpenLayers based app. I tried using `jsdom` to simulate the DOM, and ended up having to add also `xmldom`, `canvas`, and now it still won't work since it requires  `requestAnimationFrame`. So maybe I should use a different approach.

I am now looking at using `phantomjs`. Are there any examples for testing `ol3` in that way? is it feasible? Or maybe I should just test it in a normal browser?

Comment: Too bad this was shut down, I'd really like to see some responses to this.